# is memory taken up by variables declared in function scope cleared after exit?

Tags: php, performance, memory

Is the memory taken up by variables declared in function scope cleared after leaving function scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are marked for garbage collection when they loose scope. The garbage collection then kicks in when necessary, which may not be immediately. However, functions created by [create_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) are not subject to this and can cause memory leaks. Since 5.3 there is even some real [garbage collection](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) for longer scripts. Read more [here](http://phpmaster.com/better-understanding-phps-garbage-collection/).

Comment: Andreas, thank you very much. I just found this interesting article http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/18/1/10 , still reading it but I liked the first statement: PHP performs garbage collection at three primary junctures:

When you tell it to

When you leave a function

When the script ends

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course the memory is cleared upon running the function

Answer (score 0):

Not immediately. Most GC'd languages do their 'collecting' in bursts - either when it's deemed necessary due to heapspace constraints or, depending on the strategy if there is nothing else to do during the course of execution.